# Getting specific firefox source snapshots for installed firefox in lucid(or whichever)

Tags: firefox, debugging, source

I can get LATEST snapshots with bzr no problem.  What I am trying to do is get source snapshots for the installed version of firefox on ubuntu distribution whatever.  I googled around a bit and it all comes back to use bzr to get source latest.

`apt-get source firefox-3.5` pulls in something, but it doesn't contain source files.  I could be mistaken on this, but I don't see anything other than the debian directory.  Any guidance?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? If you're not sure, post the output of `lsb_release -sr`

Comment: I'm using 10.04 LTS with ff3.5 (package is labeled 3.5, but the binary is labeled 3.6) on the box in question...although I thought a general response would be most useful for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is contained in a tarball, which you need to extract:

```
apt-get source firefox
cd firefox_3.6.16+build1+nobinonly
tar xjvf mozilla-1.9.2-3.6.16+build1-source.tar.bz2
cd mozilla
```

Comment: thx.  I was having a bonehead moment.